What factors contribute to LED degradation over time?
As I understand it, LEDs can break down in two main ways: excessive current, which can cause the LED to blow on start-up, and high temperatures, which can burn out the LED. But what about long-term situations when the LEDs are operating according to the manufacturer's specifications and are properly cooled?

The book you want to buy and read is "Optoelectronics: Fiber-Optics Applications Manual" from Hewlett-Packard, 2nd edition. I may have bought up most of them, all I could find at the time. My apologies. But you may find one available, somewhere. It covers everything about what you are asking here. And I mean everything.

@periblepsis Well, if you've been so "greedy" with them, perhaps scanning a copy and linking the archive would be in order? :) Actually, looks like archive.org has you beat: https://archive.org/details/optoelectronicsf0000hewl perhaps some highlights (you sound like an excellent guide to relevant content in the tome) would make a fine answer!

Current, which causes heat, is the main factor that causes LED degradation.  The closer its operated to its maximum current rating, the shorter the life.

Don't discount ESD if the LED can be touched by a human.

Thanks for the book reference and all the answers you've given!

@CarlRutschow If you know that as a fact you should post it as an answer, not a comment. If you guess, it should not even be a comment.

@periblepsis I guess that's the follow-up to what was only named "Optoelectronics Applications Manual" from 1977? Kinda weird to rename a book while also calling it 2nd edition! But I agree on its quality.

LED suffer from lumen depreciation and color shift over time. Such can be speed up by external factors; like VoCs. In midpower LEDs, eg sulphur can blacken the silver mirror around the die. Also the silicone can age over time. However, when the LED is operated within their datasheet conditions (operating current, package and junction temperature) the main degradation is coming form external factors like UV, VoC etc.
Dust has no negative impact on the output, except that it can block photons and hence increase temperature. Please do NOT use glue. such is not needed and can contain VoC.
I don't understand above 'problem with the wavelength' all LEDs are binned on wavelength/color point, hence at 0h the spread is small.
Proper LED manufacturers provide reliability tests data and an LM-80 test report, showing lumen depreciation over time.

I assume "VoC" is volatile organic compound?  This answer isn't complete without spelling it out.  Also, do you really mean "silicone" (rubber), which would fall into the category of "glue" and definitely contains volatile organics?

And if you don't mean silicone but rather silicon, LEDs do not contain silicon. The majority of LEDs are some form of indium aluminum gallium nitride, a direct-bandgap semiconductor (hence more efficient emission than the indirect-bandgap silicon) with a bandgap that can be tuned by changing the proportions of indium, aluminum, and gallium. Silicon LEDs would be highly inefficient and would only ever emit in the infrared (I am unsure if IR LEDs are ever silicon, or if they too always use a direct-bandgap semiconductor, however).

I have done my internship in an LED manufacturing company, as i understood, in most cases some leds burn out due to moisture or dust, in such cases its useful to add glue between each led pixel, moreover mask your board to prevent any foreign body to interact with the led board, also electronics at the back side of the board after long usage interact and burn due to heat, in such cases it is useful to spray the board with specific fluid to prevent interactions, Lastly, sometimes we cant control the behavior of the LED as it come with problem due to its wavelength, its impossible to manufacture an LED with a specific wavelength continuously as it depends on electromagnetic radiations, such cases are not rare so LED burn naturally after some age due to wavelength, such problem cant be fixed unless aging the LED  to check for performance and replacing the leds that will burn before selling the board

Can you add more detail on "specific fluid" and how LEDs burn due to moisture or dust?

I dont recall the fluid exactly, but i believe if you search about pcb board spraying you will figure it out, for the moisture and dust, i witnessed the manufacturer taking these precautions such as masking the pcb because the panel was subjected to outdoor placement
